# Apart from localhost, solr is not running through anywhere

Tags: solr

Hi
I have installed solr with jetty, now the issue is that i can run the jetty through localhost by typing the following url http://local:8983/solr/admin but cannot do the same from another system in the network by typing the ip address of the machine on which the solr is installed.
Also in the mid i got the 404 error on the server machine (the machine on which solr is installed), when i typed the following url:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin
But this problem did not arise again after restarting the server.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are the required details:
O/S: Fedora core 8
Apache solr 1.4.0

Comment: Did you check the firewall and open port 8983?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you run SOLR it outputs at the end that "SOLR connect listening from/at 0.0.0.0.0  port 8983" which means its listening to calls from all the outside IP. See if you have the same output.

Also, telnet to the local IP port to confirm in case you are able to ping/ssh to that machine.